# development environment for Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, development-environment

Do I have to have the same SharePoint 2013 version in the Development Env and Production? 
Could I have SP2013 Foundation in dev and Enterprise in Prod?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to compare features and decide whether you need the same features in dev that you have in prod: http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-feature-comparison-chart-all-editions/

Comment: what if i need same features in DEv as well i have SP developer 2013, what steps i need to follow to take same data from prod to dev and database and admins part everything